# Modelica command which can select all components of the same type in a model

Tags: modelica

I am looking for a command in Modelica which can select all the components of the same type.
I want to summarize a volume of an extensive pipe system consisting of over a 100 of single dynamic pipes and save it later as a variable.

Answer (score 7):

Currently Modelica does not have that.

However, there's a proposal that would change that https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaSpecification/tree/MCP/0021/RationaleMCP/0021
It has been test-implemented in Dymola, and possibly other tools.

See also the paper:
https://ep.liu.se/ecp/118/026/ecp15118245.pdf

The other alternative would be to replace the Pipe-model with a specialized pipe-model that communicated the total volume using e.g., inner/outer.